# Filter pandas index by function

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to filter a pandas dataframe by a function along the index. I can't seem to find a built-in way of performing this action.

So essentially, I have a function that through some arbitrarily complicated means determines whether a particular index should be included, I'll call it `filter_func` for this example. I wish to apply exactly what the below code does, but to the index:

```
new_index = filter(filter_func, df.index)
```

And only include the values that the `filter_func` allows. The index could also be any type.

This is a pretty important factor of data manipulation, so I imagine there's a built-in way of doing this action.

ETA:

I found that indexing the dataframe by a list of booleans will do what I want, but still requires double the space of the index in order to apply the filter. So my question still remains if there's a built-in way of doing this that does not require twice the space.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"value":[12,34,2,23,6,23,7,2,35,657,1,324]})

def filter_func(ind, n=0):
    if n > 200: return False
    if ind % 79 == 0: return True
    return filter_func(ind+ind-1, n+1)

new_index = filter(filter_func, df)
```

And I want to do this:

```
mask = []
for i in df.index:
    mask.append(filter_func(i))
df = df[mask]
```

But in a way that doesn't take twice the space of the index to do so

Comment: using loc: `df.loc[new_index]`  ? or if your function returns the position of the indices instead of the index labels,  change `loc` to `iloc`

Comment: `filter_func` returns a boolean. The built in `filter` function returns an iterable of the filtered list. As such, in this case `new_index` will be a lazy iterable of the filtered index

Comment: `new_index` is essentially a list so it doesn't work. If I use the raw `new_index` pandas doesn't recognise the `filter` object, but if I convert it to a list with `list(new_index))`, it doesn't work because it isn't hashable. Event converting it to a hashable type (such as a `tuple`), pandas still can't index using it

Comment: @anky I edited to add the extra info and a mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use map instead of filter and then do a boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[map(filter_func,df.index)]
```

---

```
   value
0     12
4      6
7      2
8     35
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using df.apply?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df[df.apply(lambda x: x['c']%2 == 0, axis = 1)]
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
2  6  7  8
```

You can customize the lambda function in any way you want, let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: This wouldn't work with the example function I gave, as the function I gave works on an index basis, where as apply expects a function that applys a boolean check to the entire dataframe. This is very restricting, as it prevents you from applying different checks to different indexes, which an arbitrary function would be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid referencing df explicitly inside the filtering condition, you can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"value":[12,34,2,23,6,23,7,2,35,657,1,324]}, dtype=object)

df.apply(lambda x: x if filter_func(x.name) else None, axis=1, result_type='broadcast').dropna()
```